# Using knit2pdf with Rmd files

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is it possible to use the knitr function knit2pdf() directly with R Markdown (Rmd) files? I've seen various tutorials/class notes that seem to suggest it can e.g. [here](http://bcb.dfci.harvard.edu/~aedin/courses/ReproducibleResearch/Reports.Rmd) and [here](http://cbcb.umd.edu/~hcorrada/CFG/homeworks/HW1.html) (Ctrl+F "knit2pdf" in either).

But when I take a simple rmd file (saved as "test.rmd")

````
---
title: "knit2pdf test"
author: "A Aaronson"
date: "Thursday, February 19, 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

and try

```
library(knitr)
knit2pdf("test.Rmd")
```

I get the following error

results in:

```
output file: test.md

Error: running 'texi2dvi' on 'test.md' failed

LaTeX errors:
! Emergency stop
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\PROGRA~2\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\texi2dvi.exe" --quiet --pdf "test.md" --max-iterations=20 -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1
```

Clicking the "Knit PDF" button always successfully generates a pdf. So am I missing an intermediate step?

I should add that knit2pdf() with Rnw files is working as expected for me, though I do still get the warning

```
running command '"C:\PROGRA~2\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\texi2dvi.exe" --quiet --pdf "rnwtest.tex" --max-iterations=20 -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1
```

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Checking ?knit2pdf, I see that knit2pdf() expects an Rnw or Rrst document which is why "knit2pdf() with Rnw files is working as expected" but not with Rmd. I think "Clicking the "Knit PDF" button always successfully generates a pdf" because an Rnw or rst version is generated in a preliminary step and then knit2pdf() called on the result to produce the pdf (or something like that). So you need to figure out how to produce the rst version from your Rmd, then use rst2pdf()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your input file is in `rmarkdown` format.

You should use the `render()` function in the `rmarkdown` package to compile your document.

Try:

```
library("rmarkdown")
render("temp.rmd")
```

[image]